# Tabbed Content in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I am doing tabbed content in PHP & Bootstrap that pulls the data dynamically from the database. So i can successfull pull the number and generate the array from how many data i selected. I chose 3 then 3 tabs will be generated.

My problem is, the content for those 3 are all the same. Please help me what i am doing wrong here. It seems my loops are doing fine logically.

```
<?php
    $date = $_POST['handinDate'];
    $baseId = $_POST['base'];
    $deviceNum = $_POST['device'];
    $flightsCount = $_POST['flights'];
    $newDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($date));
?>


<div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">    
            <?php 
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($flightsCount); $i++){
                    if ($i == 0){
                        echo "<li class='active'><a href='content$flightsCount[$i]' data-toggle='tab'>GA $flightsCount[$i]</a></li>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<li><a href='content$flightsCount[$i]' data-toggle='tab'>GA $flightsCount[$i]</a></li>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> SALES RECORD # ~ <b><?php echo $newDate.'/SR-SOB-'.$deviceNum.'-1'; ?></b></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- GENERATING TAB CONETENT HERE -->
            <?php
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($flightsCount); $i++){
                    if ($i == 0){
                        echo "<div class='tab-pane active' id='content$flightsCount[$i]'>";
                            echo "<b>SALES ORDER # = $date~$flightsCount[$i]</b>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='tab-pane' id='content$flightsCount[$i]'>";
                            echo "<b>SALES ORDER # = $date~$flightsCount[$i]</b>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
      </div><!-- nav-tabs-custom -->
</div>
```

Comment: Is `$flightsCount` supposed to be an Array when you do `count($flightsCount)` and `$flightsCount[$i]`? Because the name suggests it's a number.

Comment: yes $flightsCount came from  $flightsCount = $_POST['flights']; and the data sent is like this for 3 flights , flights[] 
74
flights[] 
76
flights[] 
78

Comment: yes exactly.... my purpose at the end is to submit every data from different at the same time into the details_flight in my database

Comment: Right now, with what you said, it's hard to say what's wrong. You should show a minimal code example to reproduce the issue (without all the extra HTML, so that it is easier to look at) along with input data, what you get, and what you _should_ get.

Comment: ok blex lets say from the input the array content is 2 flight 76 & 78. It can generate 2 tabs 76 and 78. and if i click tab 76 it should show SALES ORDER # = 2016/04/15~76 and if i choose 78 it should show SALES ORDER # = 2016/04/15~78 in their respective tab window.

Comment: Ok then I think your issue is not with your PHP code, but with your HTML. Your links' `href` are supposed to link to each tab, but for that, you need to add `#` in front of them. E.g: `<a href='`#`content$flightsCount[$i]' data-toggle='tab'>GA ...</a>`